# When updating an object in a document it converts to string

Tags: c#, mongodb, object

I have a document that one of its properties (`InfoContent`) is an object.
When I update the document the object converts to string (json). What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var updatedef = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<ClientData>();

UpdateDefinition<ClientData> updef;
updef = updatedef.Set("InfoContent", BsonDocument.Parse(req.Params.InfoContent))
                                       .Set(c => c.ClientId, req.Params.ClientId)
                                       .Set(c => c.UpdateDate, DateTime.Now.toDateTimeUTC())
                                       .Set(c => c.Deleted, req.Params.Deleted)
                                       .Set("UpdateId", req.Params.UpdatedId);

var col = _Database.GetCollection<ClientData>("PatientStoreInfo");                  

UpdateResult ur = col.UpdateOne<ClientData>(x => x._id == ObjectId.Parse(req.Params.RecordId), updef);
```

Comment: Why do you think it is converted to a string? What is the evidence?

Comment: Hi Tamas, when I view it using Robo 3T it shows that the type is string.